# «Как бы кто не думал». Верно написано?

Tags: не-или-ни

«Как бы кто не/ни думал». *Не* или *ни*?

Answer (score 3):

Корректно: «Как бы кто ни думал». 
Здесь нет отрицания (не думал). Наоборот, здесь говорится, что люди **думают**, думают по-разному, но в любом случае (как бы кто ни думал) что-то происходит. **Ни — усилительная частица**.